problem booting to Ubuntu 22.04
after completing dual booting ubuntu 22.04 on my already installed windows 11, I used ubuntu for 2 days and installed some applications on it, but now after accessing my windows 11 using the bitlocker recovery key anytime I start my computer I go straight to my windows and I don't get the option to boot into ubuntu. what can I do?
I tried using try ubuntu from BIOS/EFI and install grub, but I got this error: cannot open '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi'
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi

then, bind the directories and:
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/nvme0n1

and there is when the error pops up.
I really appreciate your help on this matter.
